# Problems understanding how set works

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Can someone please help me understand the following code segment?

```
set -- ${BACKUPDIR}/backup-???.tgz
lastname=${!#}
backupnr=${lastname##*backup-}
backupnr=${backupnr%%.*}
backupnr=${backupnr//\?/0}
backupnr=$[10#${backupnr}]
```

I found it in this backup script 
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Skripte/inkrementelles_Backup/ 
where it is used to get the number of the filename of the last stored backup. The filenames of the backups are "backup-ccc.tgz" where ccc is a three digit number that is incremented every time a new backup is created.

I do understand lines three and four they cut off the rest of the filename so just the needed part with the number is left. What I don't get is how the first two lines are working. I read the manpage of set but now I'm confused more then I had been before. What does the command `set -- filename` do? Also what exactly is the option ${!#} for, that is being stored in lastname. I think ${} is to dereference a given parameter, but which parameter does the option !# point to?

Secondly I don't get why I need the command in line 5. As I understand this is used to replace all question marks with an 0 that are stored in the variable backupnr, but why is this done? If there hasn't been an error in the commands before backupnr should be a three digit number, if there has been an error and the content of the variable is corrupt, you can't know what is the actual value of backupnr. So if I want to scan for corruption why don't I have to scan for everything thats not a number, but just for a question mark? Is this maybe somehow related to whats happening in the first two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set` is often used to set the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc., which are usually provided as arguments to the script). By using these parameters, we can get a simple way to count things via the `$#` variable, which stores the number of set positional parameters.

`?` is a wildcard matching any single character, so `???` matches any combination of three characters.

Combined: `set -- ${BACKUPDIR}/backup-???.tgz` sets every file named `backup-xxx.tgz`, where `xxx` are any three characters, as the parameters.

`${!#}`, uses [variable indirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), it
>   introduces a level of variable indirection. Bash uses the value of the
>   variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the
>   variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the
>   rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.
>   This is known as indirect expansion.

Since `$#`, which is what you get when you remove the `!`, is the count of parameters (and the number of the last parameter), `${!#}` is a simple way to get the last argument.

---

As for command 5, what happens when no matching files are present?

```
$ bash -c 'set -- backup-???.tgz; echo "$@"'
backup-???.tgz
```

The shell leaves that word alone, so now we have just a literal `backup-???.tgz`. The author handles that edge case by replacing the `?` with `0`, to mark the first backup file.

Comment: So if I use `set`, I will create a new positional parameter, which will always have the index of the last already existing parameter incremented by one?

But why is the author using `set -- ${BACKUPDIR}/backup-???.tgz` and not just `set ${BACKUPDIR}/backup-???.tgz` without the --?

Comment: @Asco there's not telling whet `BACKUPDIR` might contain. `set` can also be used to set the shell options (`set -e`, `set -f`, etc.). To be safe, the `--` tells `set` to stop treating the remaining arguments as options ot `set`.